# ECDSA: How to get y coordinate from uncompressing x using openssl

Tags: openssl, compression, point, ecdsa

What I am trying to do with ECDSA is take an x "compressed" coordinate and a y "bit" from values taken from external ECDSA hardware (it's really a public key) and then trying to recover the y coordinate (uncompressed) with OpenSSL function calls.

I am trying the following code, but it does not work as I expected (my xy[] array does not get populated with correct data).  Can anyone help?

I'm new to ECDSA and even newer to OpenSSL, but I was thinking I could do the following:

```
EC_GROUP *curve_group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime192v1);
EC_POINT *point;
BIGNUM *x_compressed = BN_new();
int y_chooser_bit = 1;
int results = 0;
size_t returnsize = 0;
 
unsigned char x_compressed_byte_array[25] = {0x02, 0x71, 0xc0, 0x73, 0x73, 
                                             0x9b, 0xbf, 0xc2, 0x0a, 
                                             0x81, 0xcd, 0xdd, 0xf4, 
                                             0xcf, 0xca, 0xc7, 0xb5, 
                                             0xa9, 0x99, 0x61, 0x23, 
                                             0x2c, 0x5c, 0x63, 0x7a};

unsigned char xy[49];

// create a big number from the unsigned char array
BN_bin2bn(&x_compressed_byte_array[0],200,NULL); // length is in bits?

point = EC_POINT_new(curve_group);

results = EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp(curve_group, point, 
                                                  x_compressed,                                                               
                                                  y_chooser_bit, NULL);

returnsize = EC_POINT_point2oct(curve_group, point, 
                                POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED, 
                                &xy[0], 49, NULL); // 49

// clean up allocated memory
BN_free(x_compressed);
EC_POINT_free(point);
EC_GROUP_free(curve_group);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of your code

```
BN_bin2bn(&x_compressed_byte_array[0],200,NULL); // length is in bits?
```

You should pass bn_compressed, the BIGNUM you created, to hold the converted result. And the length is in bytes.

```
BN_bin2bn(&x_compressed_byte_array[0],sizeof(x_compressed_byte_array),x_compressed);
```

After you set_compressed_coordinates, you can verify if the point you just created locate correctly in the group.

```
if (!EC_POINT_is_on_curve(curve_group,point,NULL)) return 0;
```

To further examine the point coordinates (x,y), you can place this in your code.

```
if (!EC_POINT_get_affine_coordinates_GFp(curve_group, point, x, y, NULL)) return 0;
fprintf(stdout, "\point = (x,y)\n");
fprintf(stdout, "     x = 0x");
BN_print_fp(stdout, x);
fprintf(stdout, "\n     y = 0x");
BN_print_fp(stdout, y);
fprintf(stdout, "\n");
```

Just remember to new/free BIGNUM x and y at the first/end of your function.

```
BIGNUM *x, *y;
x = BN_new();
y = BN_new();

/* your code */

if(x) BN_free(x);
if(y) BN_free(y);
```

And it should work. The result xy[49] I have is

0x0471C073739BBFC20A81CDDDF4CFCAC7B7A99961232C5C637C388AB06AA7E43A2B5CFE2D7F3AC2DF910D6F8D8F209CD817

Comment: Thank you so much ChiaraHsieh!  I was able to replicate your answer (the xy[49]).  Now, my only confusion is how best to handle the compressed x key.  The code above uses 25 bytes for the compressed key for a 192-bit curve, but maybe I should have used 24 bytes and simply relied on passing the "y_bit"?  So, I guess my question is:  does OPENSSL require the extra byte of the compressed key or, should I use the 24-byte x-coordinate with the y-bit?  THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: You're welcome. :) You need 25 bytes. The first byte indicates that the x-coordinate is in either uncompressed, or hybrid, or compressed form. For example, the first byte of x `0x02` is indicating that x is in compressed form. The first byte of xy `0x04` indicates that xy is in uncompressed form. OPENSSL needs this indicator, and of course, ybit, together to correctly recover the ec_point (x,y). Point compression is defined in X9.62 standard if you need any reference.